# AngularJs injection error

Tags: angularjs

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http, $interval, $state, $location)
{
}

angular
    .module('inspinia', ['angularCharts'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
```

No matter what I try to inject, I get an error. Instructions are not very clear. For instance, should I be pulling in the script which has the injection before or after Angur itself? Etc, etc

Is there anything obviouslty wrong with that code above?

**IMPORTANT** this is an exisitng, fuctcioning app. As pointed out in the comments, the error seems clear, BUT it only occurs when I add `, ['angularCharts']`. Before that, the coude is working just fine, routing, state chanegs and all.

I suspect that the erorr message is a red herring. The problem obvoulsy stems from adding `, ['angularCharts']` - but why?

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state <- MainCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider%20%3C-%20%24state%20%3C-%20MainCtrl
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4397
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4550)
    at angular.js:4402
    at getService (angular.js:4550)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4574)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4596)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:9855)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8927)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8226)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13236(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9965Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16925bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1694invoke @ angular.js:4604doBootstrap @ angular.js:1692bootstrap @ angular.js:1712angularInit @ angular.js:1606(anonymous function) @ angular.js:30423j @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2I @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
```

---

[Update] I am basing the app on a framework.  I don't know how good it is, but it does work (state change and all).

INdex.html has `<script src="js/app.js"></script>`

which file contains the following. Maybe I should be adding `['angularCharts']` there?  In fact, is it wrong of me to have that `.module` line at the end of my controller?

```
(function () {
    angular.module('inspinia', [
        'ui.router',                    // Routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
        'ui.bootstrap',                 // Ui Bootstrap
    ])
})();
```

Comment: There is no single injection in the code you posted, and no error message either.

Comment: You should probably post the error as well.

Comment: @jbnizet I thoguht that I was trying to inject `angularCharts`.  I copied from a Plunk, but obviously did not copy well enough.   I am trying to fir charts into an existing app

Comment: You're confusing "injecting a component into another component (for example, a service `$state` into a controller `MainCtrl`), and "declaring module dependencies" (for example, `.module('inspinia', ['angularCharts'])`defines a new module 'inspinia' which has a dependency on the module 'angularCharts'). The latter simply means that when the 'inspinia' module is loaded, all itscomponents and all the components of 'angularCharts' ara available in the application or test.

Comment: Pro tip: There's a URL in the error message that gives you more information about the error.

Comment: Regarding your error: it would be much clearer if you didn't use the minified version of angular, which should be used in producion, but not in development. And it says that MainCtrl needs a service named `$state`, which is not available. You have forgotten to make your module depend on the ui-router module.

Comment: Thanks. I will not use minified. Strange, becuase the code is working, with `$state`  until I add that `, ['angularCharts']`

Comment: @jbnizet, I updated the question qute a bit. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer is still the same. MainCtrl clearly needs the $state service. And it's not available, because your module has no dependency on ui-router. Note that `.module('inspinia', ['angularCharts'])` **defines** (or **redefines** if already defined before) the module 'inspinia'. If it has already been defined before with a dependency on ui-router, then you're redefining it with a dependency on angularCharts, but no dependency on ui-router anymore. And losing all the previously added components too. Don't do that. Find the unique definition of the module and add the new dependency there.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks **very** much for you patience so far. I am using soemone else's framework. Please see the update at the bottom of the question. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, that's where the new dependency on angularCharts must be added. The controller file must not **redefine** the module as you're doing. It must only **get a reference** to the module: `angular.module('inspinia').controller(...)`. Angular unfortunately chose to use a single function to **define** (when there is an array of dependencies as second argument) and **retrieve** (when there is no second argument) a module. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Comment: @JBNizet, Yay!! `angular.js:13236 Error: Please set height and width for the chart element` - never has an error emssage looked so sweet :-) Obvioulsy I am now into charting land & making progress. I can't give a bonus ot a comment, but if you will post an answer, I will award it.

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're **redefining** the main module of your application when doing

```
angular.module('inspinia', ['angularCharts'])
```

So the module loses all its components previously added, and all its dependencies (ui-router, etc.).

Instead, you must modify the axisting definition of the module to add a dependency on angularCharts, and, in your controller, simply retrieve the previously defined module:

```
angular.module('inspinia').controller(...);
```